# Password Regular Expression is not working with RadInputManager?

Tags: regex

I am using Teleriks RadInputManager control to check that a password is between 7 and 16 characters and contains at least 1 numeric and 1 special character, but when I type something that I know fits the expression, validation fails, so I believe my regular expression is wrong.  Here is the expression I am using:

```
/^(?=.{7,16}$)\D+\d/
```

I tried the following:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@&.$#]).{7,16}$/
```

and tried to put the password test11. and it failed.  I don't understand why because this is 7 characters and contains a numeric and a special character.

Comment: I believe using a single RegEx is wrong in this situation.

Comment: Don't be that guy who makes a password requirement that actually hurts security. Get rid of the 16 character maximum. If someone wants a 30 character password, why stop them?

Comment: `if (password.length >= 7 && /\d/.test(password) && /[!@#$etc]/.test(password))`

Comment: @Brian Schroth:  I agree with you, unfortunately, I don't make the rules, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[-;:]).{7,16}$/
```

You didn't specify what a special character is so I just used an example, but you'll have to replace it with something better.

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to regular expressions, but I am assuming anything between [ ] can be used as a special character, correct?

Comment: Also, what exactly is a lookahead, I was looking at an indepth link that was explaining it before, but I got lost in translation, I just need a simple to understand example.

Comment: Xaisoft: Yes any character can be written there, but you have to be careful with characters like `-`, `\` and `]` as these have a special meaning inside character classes and need to be escaped.

Comment: Sorry that should have been: you have to be careful with: `-`, `\ ` and `]`. Apparently I need to be careful with these too.

Comment: Mark, that was the link that I was actually looking at and although it was extremely helpful, I think because I don't have an understanding of doing it without a lookhead, I don't see the real value of a lookahead.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Doing it in one regular expression without a lookahead would be crazy complicated. Using lookaheads allows you to test the three conditions separately instead of having to write one state machine that remembers the state of all three parts of the regular expressions simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the regular expression to /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[.$#]).{7,16}$/. Note the special characters, is that the correct way to put it?