# Confused on why this regular expression does not work?

Tags: regex

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@&.$#]).{7,16}$/
```

It should allow between 7 and 16 characters and contain at least 1 numeric character and 1 special character and can't start with a number.  I tried testing it but it does not work?

Comment: How come my password can't start with a number...

Comment: @KennyTM: Who said this is used to test a password?

Comment: @Gumbo: Have you saw his/her previous question? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282889/password-regular-expression-is-not-working-with-radinputmanager)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that I assume "does not work", which is a bit of a vague problem description to be honest, is the fact that it CAN start with a digit. Besides that, it works as you described.

Fix it like this:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@&.$#])\D.{6,15}$/
```

A short explanation (in case you did not write the regex yourself):

```
^             # match the beginning of the input
(?=           # start positive look ahead
  .*          #   match any character except line breaks and repeat it zero or more times
  \d          #   match a digit: [0-9]
)             # end positive look ahead
(?=           # start positive look ahead
  .*          #   match any character except line breaks and repeat it zero or more times
  [!@&.$#]    #   match any character from the set {'!', '#', '$', '&', '.', '@'}
)             # end positive look ahead
\D            # match a non-digit: [^0-9]
.{6,15}       # match any character except line breaks and repeat it between 6 and 15 times
$             # match the end of the input
```

Comment: I tried the above with the password test11. and it it said it was invalid.

Comment: @Xaisoft, the string `test11.` (including the DOT) works just fine.

Comment: must be a telerik issue. I test yours fine in another program and it worked fine.

Comment: @Xaisoft, `6,16` way a mistake: it should've been `6,15` (not `7,16`). The first character that'll be matched is a `\D` (non-digit) after which between 6 and 15 other characters should follow (`1+6,1+15` == `7,16`).

Comment: Thanks.  I really appreciate the breakdown.  How does it know not to allow a non-digit in the beginning. It seems to go in order, so I would think \D would be somewhere in the beginning similar to Gumbo's answer.

Comment: Xaisoft, the `\D` *is* in the beginning. The positive lookaheads don't actually consume any characters from the input. The first one says the string needs to have a digit *somewhere*, and the second lookahead says there must be one of those other characters *somewhere*. Once those two conditions are met, *then* the actual matching begins. The first character must be a non-digit, and then there must be six to 15 additional characters. The lookaheads from earlier ensure that we don't need to worry about what those characters really are.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  You made Positive Lookaheads easier to understand. So the actually matching starts after the last postive lookahead if I understood you correctly.

Comment: @Xaisoft, yes. Look arounds (ahead and behind) never match any character(s). The only "validate" from a certain position. For example, `.(?!a)` will match any **single** character that is not followed by an `a`.

Comment: @Xaisoft, note that `/^\D(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@&.$#]).{6,15}$/` is equivalent to my previous suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The first two conditions are fulfilled but the third (must not start with a digit) is not. Because `.*` in `^(?=.*\d)` does match when there is a digit at the first position.

Try this instead:

```
/^(?=\D+\d)(?=.*[!@&.$#]).{7,16}$/
```

Here `\D` (anything except a digit) ensures that that is at least one non-digit character at the start.

Comment: @Xaisoft: `test11.` works for me. What language/regular expression implementation do you use?

Comment: I tested it in an online Regular Expression tester and it does work.  I am using it in Teleriks RadInputManager's RegExpTextBoxSetting.  It is c# and asp.net in the background.

Comment: I got it, apparently, there is no reason to add the / at the beginning and end when specifying the expression with telerik.  It would have be nice if they specified this though.